# Error 'module' object is not callable in Pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

can someone tell me what is wrong with this code?

```
class Food():
    def __init__(self, image_name, width, height):
        self.unt_image = pygame.image.load(image_name)
        self.image = pygame.transform(self.unt_image, (width, height))
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(50, 50, width, height)

ice_cream = Food("icecream.png", 30, 70)
```

I keep getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
    File "c:\Users\jachy\Nová složka\chytej.py", line 15, in <module> ice_cream = Food("icecream.png", 30, 70) 
    File "c:\Users\jachy\Nová složka\chytej.py", line 12, in init self.image = pygame.transform(self.unt_image, (width, height)) 
    TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: Can you share the complete error message?

Comment: And where do you get this error? Please provide us with the exact and full error message.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\jachy\Nová složka\chytej.py", line 15, in <module>
    ice_cream = Food("icecream.png", 30, 70)
  File "c:\Users\jachy\Nová složka\chytej.py", line 12, in __init__
    self.image = pygame.transform(self.unt_image, (width, height))
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: Well, one `load`, `transform` or `Rect`, is not a function nor a class but a module and you're trying to call it. It's probably not `Rect`, because classes in python are almost always capitalized, so either `load` or `transform`, is a module.

Comment: [`transform`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html) is a module, not a function.

Comment: Are you telling me i can not call a module this way? Because all of these are in pygame module.

Comment: I mean, how can I solve this if i can't use transform this way? I have to transform the image outside of the class?

Comment: What transformation are you trying to use? There's many like flip/rotate/scale. Your code isn't calling any specific one

Comment: Oh gosh am I that stupid? Yes I am.. Sorry for bothering and thanks for help

Comment: There are many ways to transform as shown in the [pygame.transform docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html). You can't just "transform", but you could flip or scale or rotate.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

`pygame.transform` is a module.

It's not clear what you are trying to do with the image that's loaded, but [`pygame.transform.scale()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.scale), for example, is a function that would resize something to a width/height